# Computational complexity of testing matrix orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a real-valued square matrix $A$, what are the minimal number of operations required to test whether $A$ is orthogonal? For example, $AA^T$ is symmetric such that only half needs to be computed. Are there other possible savings?